What is the correct solution to work with bitmaps in terms of pointer arithmetic and conversion?
When working with bitmaps, it nearly always mandatory that every row of the image begins at a 4-byte boundary. This can lead to padding, in cases where the bitdepth of the image is less than 32 bytes.
Example: An 24 bit RGB image has 3 bytes per pixel and if the width of the image is 1026 pixels, then one line contains 1026 * 3 bytes = 3078 bytes. 3078 is not divisible by 4, so we need to add 2 bytes for padding to form a full scanline.
The space in bytes needed for one row is often called pitch.
This means I cannot simply use a formula like y * width + x to access the pixel at (x, y), instead I must do some sort of pointer arithmetic.
Let's say I have a struct to access one pixel and a struct that contains the image value:
struct PixelRGB24
{
  unsigned char r, g, b;
};

struct ImageRGB24
{
  unsigned int width;
  unsigned int heigth;
  unsigned int pitch;
  void *pixels;
};

Which code is conform with the C++ standard (no undefined behaviour)? (omitted boundary checks for simplicity)

Weird pointer arithmetic

PixelRGB24 GetPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, ImageRGB24 *image)
{
  PixelRGB24 *pixel = reinterpret_cast<PixelRGB24 *>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(image->pixels) + y * image->pitch + 3 * x);

  return *pixel;
}


Casting chain void * to char * to void * to PixelRGB24

PixelRGB24 GetPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, ImageRGB24 *image)
{
  char *row_offset = static_cast<char *>(image->pixels) + y * image->pitch;
  void *pixel_offset_raw = static_cast<void *>(pixel_offset);
  PixelRGB24 *pixel = static_cast<PixelRGB24 *>(pixel_offset_raw) + x;
  return *pixel;
}


Same as 2., but with reinterpret_cast to avoid void * conversion step

PixelRGB24 GetPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, ImageRGB24 *image)
{
  char *row_offset = static_cast<char *>(image->pixels) + y * image->pitch;
  PixelRGB24 *pixel = reinterpret_cast<PixelRGB24 *>(pixel_offset_raw) + x;
  return *pixel;
}

Or do all three implementations cause undefined behaviour and if so, what is the correct solution?

Libraries which stores three pixels per byte is almost never going to care about alignment; libraries that care about alignment are almost always going to either use one, two, or four bytes per pixel, or else store 2, 4, or 8 pixels per byte.

Consider that some implementations (compilers and/or architectures) might silently pad a three-byte structure to something larger (like 4 bytes).

@supercat SDL does (SDL_Surface, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24), OpenGL does (GL_RGB), Windows does (CreateBitmap), just to name a few. And even with 1 or 2 bytes per pixel you would have the alignment problem (301 pixels * 2 bytes per pixel = 602 bytes, padding needed).

"1. Weird pointer arithmetic" -- This does not demonstrate pointer arithmetic. You explicitly cast the pointer to an integer before performing the arithmetic. Maybe "Simulated pointer arithmetic" would be more accurate?

In #2, is pixel_offset supposed to be row_offset?

"Same as 2., but with reinterpret_cast to avoid void * conversion step" -- There is no avoidance here. A reinterpret_cast from one pointer to another is "exactly equivalent" to your two static_casts (to void* then to the destination pointer type). So the third implementation is really just syntactic sugar for the second. You could drop the second or third and focus on the other two.

The validity of 2 and 3 depend on how the pixels field is initialized (due to strict aliasing rules). The (in)validity of 1 is covered by Can std::uintptr_t be used to avoid undefined behavior of out-of-bounds pointer arithmetic? If that is not a duplicate, I think this question needs more information about pixels, especially since the type of that field is void* (or you could skip the conversion to PixelRGB24* and focus on the arithmetic part).

@JaMiT pixels is an array of bytes in this case, where three bytes make an RGB value and each line is padded to a multiple of four, like R G B R G B R G B P P P (width=3). I could also throw the struct away and read the bytes one after another. But other image formats are maybe "packed" 16 bit per pixel, pixels would then point to to uint16_t's and the layout in memory would be RGB RGB RGB P P (three uint16_t for width=3 and 2 padding bytes).

@Mario "pixels is an array of bytes in this case" -- That is not evident in the question. You could, though, make it evident by changing the type of pixels from void* to std::byte*. There are two side-benefits of this change. One is getting rid of void*, which is code smell in C++. The other is that implementations 2 and 3 would no longer need the initial static_cast<char*>.

Modern processors can still fetch 24 bit quantities.  The fetching may not be as efficient as a 32-bit fetch, but it is still possible.  My understanding is that the processor will fetch 24 bits into a 32-bit quantity and deal with the 32-bit register.

Also, many bitmaps include additional channels to help round out the data to a nice alignment boundary.  For example, you could have R-G-B-Alpha, which would fit nicely in a 32-bit word, with 8-bits per channel.  I've seen also R-G-B-Intensity.  Be aware that there is a limit to the colors, shades and intensities that the human eye can recognize.  24 bits per color is a lot more than the human eye can distinguish.

In C++ try to avoid raw pointer arithmetic and certainly avoid void*. Use std::vector<PixelRGB24> pixels; instead.

Were does the pixels come from? Who is in charge of its lifetime? What's the prototype of the API functions that give acsses to picture data? The actual best practices rely on this answers.

@Red.Wave It's an SDL_Surface. https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL3/SDL_Surface

@Mario you gave me a hard time finding the essentials that a proper answer would need. Unless you are the developer of the library, C struct data members are not at your disposal to use. Obviously SDL_Surface is supposed to be placed on heap; that's you are supposed to use PIMPL, because the implementation of the type is version dependent. Touching its members is not wise,  unless there's any specific function that exposes pixels. Just use std::unique_ptr on SDL_Surface with SDL_DestroySurface as the deleter.

The question about pointer arithmetic is covered by Can std::uintptr_t be used to avoid undefined behavior of out-of-bounds pointer arithmetic? (answer: no, don't use uintptr_t to do pointer arithmetic), so I'll treat this question as asking only about the conversion.

A reinterpret_cast to PixelRGB24* followed by a dereference is valid if the data was constructed as an array of PixelRGB24 objects. Otherwise, it is invalid (but tends to work, if portability is not a concern). Given that there is assumed padding between some objects, this would require an advanced construction technique to pull off (pixels would be an array of bytes that "provide storage" for PixelRGB24 objects). Since this advanced technique was not mentioned, and since the code uses void* (code smell), I am going to infer that we are not in that situation.
Before we proceed further, I would like to impose some corrections to the types of fields in the structs. The components of a pixel are not characters; they are 8-bit numbers. Also, the image data is not some unknown type; it is a sequence of bytes that will be interpreted as pixel data. Fixing the type of pixels has an advantage in reducing the number of casts needed later. It is valid regardless of how the pixel data is constructed because three "byte pointers" – char*, unsigned char*, and std::byte* – are special in that they can be used to examine the data of any object. That is, for these types, unlike for PixelRGB24*, it is valid to reinterpret_cast to them and dereference.
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

struct PixelRGB24
{
    uint8_t r, g, b; // <-- semantically numbers, not characters
};

struct ImageRGB24
{
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int heigth;
    unsigned int pitch;
    std::byte *pixels; // <-- raw data, not unknown/void
};

The good news is that PixelRGB24 (either version) is trivially copyable, so its data can be simply copied using std::memcpy. The thing to be concerned with for this approach is whether or not the compiler added padding to PixelRGB24. Padding is problematic for both this approach and for the code in the question, so I'll just add a static_assert to detect padding (maybe it should be in the struct definition instead). On the bright side, padding in this particular struct seems unlikely in most (all?) of the common programming environments.
#include <cstring>

PixelRGB24 GetPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, ImageRGB24 *image)
{
    // Ensure that there is no padding
    PixelRGB24 retval;
    static_assert(sizeof(retval) == 3);

    // Calculate the start of the pixel (pointer arithmetic)
    auto *pixel = image->pixels + y*image->pitch + x*sizeof(retval);
    // Extract the pixel data
    std::memcpy(&retval, pixel, sizeof(retval));
    // Note: Named return value optimization avoids a second copy here. In essence,
    // the above `memcpy` makes explicit the copy that would occur when your
    // versions of the function `return *pixel;`.
    return retval;
}

The above is a common way to extract a trivially copyable object from an array of bytes. It is useful if your example is just an example and you really need to handle different pixel types, perhaps by turning the pixel type into a template parameter. However, if generality is not needed, there is another approach available in your particular situation.
When the object being extracted can be constructed from bytes, the function goes down to three lines. A caveat is that the bytes used in the construction must be one of the special types, so that dereferencing after a reinterpret_cast is valid. A benefit of this approach is that padding is no longer a concern.
PixelRGB24 GetPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, ImageRGB24 *image)
{
    auto *pixel = image->pixels + y*image->pitch + x*3;
    // `std::byte cannot initialize `uint8_t`, but `unsigned char` can.
    auto *components = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pixel);
    // Note that the "magic number" 3 in the first line is explained by the
    // three values used in the line below.
    return {*components, *(components+1), *(components+2)};
}

Another benefit of this approach is that it can be used to adapt image data to pixel data when the two do not agree on the order of the components, such as converting BGR image data to RGB pixel data (reverse the components in the return statement).
Advanced:
I think this goes beyond the scope of the question, but I'll point out that it is possible to combine the above techniques to create a function template that will get a pixel regardless of the order of the components and regardless of the size of the components. An integer sequence could be used to specify the order of the components, while memcpy could be used to extract components that are larger than a byte from the image's data. How far you take this depends on your needs (flexibility vs. over-engineering) and (if significant) on how much your compiler can optimize. Demo

Thank you. Very good explanation. My struct was very simplified, in reality I have an SDL_Surface: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL3/SDL_Surface

@Mario "in reality I have an SDL_Surface" -- That makes a significant difference for the data pointer, because SDL is written in C. In C, a void* is not code smell. Just cast it to one of the three special byte pointers in your C++ code.
